# HTML5 canvas zoom where mouse coordinates

Tags: html, canvas

How to zoom background image with drawings where mouse coordinates.

Zooming only in center with mouse event *mousewheel*

`me code:` 
http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/74MCQ/4/

Drawings with *mousedown* and *mousemove* event

**I need zoom where mouse position on image like a google maps.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotated code and a Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/asT8x/

```
// clear the canvas

ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

// save the context state

ctx.save();

// translate to the coordinate point you wish to zoom in on

ctx.translate(mouseX,mouseY);

// scale the canvas to the desired zoom level

ctx.scale(scale,scale);

// draw the image with an offset of -mouseX,-mouseY
// (offset to center image at the selected zoom point);

ctx.drawImage(img,-mouseX,-mouseY);

// restore the context to its untranslated/unrotated state

ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Okey very ynice but if i want zoom and change position this example only work to start change position